# How to border one piece of TextView

Tags: android

I'm stuck at adding a label at the end of a Textview. Or may be border some last text of a Textview.

A label such as (Hot, Trending,..etc..) must locate at the end of the title. same line with the title if having space behind, or new line if not

Please see the below screenshot

Update (Upload XML code)

bg_border_label_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
      <stroke
         android:width="2dp"
         android:color="#a30014" />
</shape>
```

item_post.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rlContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
android:layout_marginRight="16sp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imvPostImage"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
    android:background="#df7217"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPostTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imvPostImage"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imvPostImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imvPostImage"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="-3dp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:text="Alan Walker vs Coldplay - Hymn For The Weekend" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPostLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvPostTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_border_label_test"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="#a30014"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="HOT" />

<mgift.views.component.TextViewPlus
    android:id="@+id/tvPublishDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imvPostImage"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPostTitle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/text_manatee"
    android:textSize="@dimen/v4_small_size_text"
    app:font="@string/open_sans_regular"
    tools:text="3 hours ago" />
```

Current result:

[image]

Expect result (Label HOT always after the title)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a drawable and set it as the background for your `textView`, see example code for the drawable below -

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke android:width="6px" android:color="#ff0000"/>

    <padding
        android:bottom="12dp"
        android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:top="12dp" />

    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Furthermore, if you want to concatenate a particular label by the end of the text, you can create an image of that label and then use `SpannableString` to concatenate the Image after your text.

For example, you can refer the code below -

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append("Alan Walker vs Coldplay - Hymn ");
String hot = "Hot";
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_hot_label_24dp);
d.setBounds(0, 16, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
SpannableString hotSpannable= new SpannableString(hot);
hotSpannable.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
builder.append(hotSpannable);
tvPostTitle.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thank you but the background drawable is not my problem. The label must locate at the end of the title. same line with the title if having space behind, or new line if not.

Comment: You can use RelativeLayout as your parent layout, and add an element such as android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/text_view_before_label"

Comment: If the TextView has 2 line, the first line full and the second lasted half. Where's the Label position?

Comment: The label even then will be aligned after the textView, if you could update the question with the xml code of your layout, we will be able to help you better.

Comment: Just update the XML code. Please take an overview. Thanks you @hsm59

Comment: If the labels are fixed, that is only hot, etc. You can create an image for each of that and store it in the drawable, and use Spannable (ImageSpan) to concatenate it after the text.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in `Drawable`. For example : edit_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >

   <corners android:radius="0dp" />

   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

  <stroke
    android:width="3px"
    android:color="#918e8e"/>

</shape>
```

And call this name in your layout(under your TextView):

```
android:background="@drawable/edit_background"
```